# How do I get past this door on the Storm Coast?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I'm exploring the Storm Coast, trying to clear everything I can in the zone, and there's several markers for Varric's personal quest on the map:

[image: Screenshot of the DA:I Map]

As you can see in that screenshot, there's a cave marker near them. When I go there, though, all I find is this, which appears to be a door:

[image: Screenshot of a door in DA:I]

There's no option to activate it, and searching up and down the area, I can't see a way around it. So, just how *am* I supposed to get up into that area to my North-West?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The door is quest-locked until you're on the "[Red Water](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/dragon-age-inquisition/Red_Water)" quest. Once you begin that quest, the door should be open and you will be able to destroy the four Red Lyrium veins inside.